# DAO layer (builder with JOIN request). Как написать метод в DAO layer по запросу всех строк из таблицы?

Tags: java, servlet, jdbc, dao

Всем привет!
Пишу своё первое web-app на servlet, jsp. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую попытаюсь максимально подробно описать ниже, суть которой состоит в том, что я не понимаю как из resultset достать некоторые поля. Собственно ниже приведен код с описанеим:
Мой объект:

```
public class Guitar {

    private Integer id;
    private Fabric fabric;
    private String name;
    private Short strings;
    private String color;
    private Integer count;
}
```

Помимо прочих одно из полей является объект другого класса (Fabric fabric. У это класса три поля: id, name, country). По запросу в базе данных (у Guitar \ Fabric свои таблицы в базе данных соответственно с идентичными полями и типами):

```
SELECT g.id as g_id, f.name as f_name, f.country as f_country, g.name as g_name, g.strings as g_strings, g.color as g_color, g.count as g_count
    FROM shop_storage.guitar g
    JOIN fabric f on g.fabric_id = f.id
WHERE g.id = 11;
```

получаемый результат я и хочу отобразить на front-end части. В DAO layer:

```
public Optional<Guitar> getById(Integer id) {
        Guitar guitar = null;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BY_ID)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
               while (guitar == null) {
                   guitar = Guitar.builder()
                           .id(resultSet.getInt("g_id"))
                           .name(resultSet.getString("g_name"))
                           .strings(resultSet.getShort("g_strings"))
                           .color(resultSet.getString("g_color"))
                           .count(resultSet.getInt("g_count"))
                           .build();
               }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DaoException(e);
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(guitar);
    }
```

из resultset я могу достать поля только объекта Guitar, но вот два других, указанных в SELECT запросе (f_name, f_country) как достать - я не знаю. Возможно проблем в знаниях работы builder'a с JOIN запросом. В общем я в тупике :(
p.s. чтуь не забыл, вот так выглядит мой запрос в DAO:

```
private static final String GET_BY_ID = "SELECT g.id as g_id, " +
            "f.name as f_name, " +
            "f.country as f_country, " +
            "g.name as g_name, " +
            "g.strings as g_strings, " +
            "g.color as g_color, " +
            "g.count as g_count " +
            "FROM shop_storage.guitar g " +
            "JOIN shop_storage.fabric f " +
            "ON g.fabric_id = f.id " +
            "WHERE g.id = ?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно так же:

```
resultSet.getString("f_name")
```

Добавить эти поля в класс `Guitar`.
И я бы не стал в данном случае использовать паттерн `Builder`: лучше передавать все параметры через конструктор.